# Infragistics grid export to a different location

Tags: javascript, infragistics, ignite-ui

The version I'm using is 15.2 (ignite UI)

Here's the export function:

```
$.ig.GridExcelExporter.exportGrid($("#grid"),
                   {
                        fileName: 'export',
                        tableStyle: 'tableStyleLight13'
                   }
```

By default it saves under the "Download" folder. Is there anyway to change the save location? Or to display a prompt for user to choose save as location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading operations are handled by the browser, so in order to have a prompt window from where to specify different path to your computer, you should enable that from your browser.

**For example in Chrome**, you should do:

[image]

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zdravko/x6jLk2pr/1/)

```
$.ig.GridExcelExporter.exportGrid($("#grid1"), {
                    fileName: "igGrid"
```

As you will see the sample is also showing how to implement confirmation box before downloading the file.